# Trying to authenticaton with firebase using password-based account

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

why this code always turn false? so i cant add any user. at firebase i have already activated password authentication, help me to solve this.

note: i run this apps with my phone, not emulator from android studio

```
private void register(final String username, String email, String password){
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    FirebaseUser firebaseUser= auth.getCurrentUser();
                    assert firebaseUser !=null;
                    String userid = firebaseUser.getUid();

                    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);

                    HashMap<String, String> HashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    HashMap.put("id", userid);
                    HashMap.put("username", username);
                    HashMap.put("imageURL", "default");

                    reference.setValue(HashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "You can't register with this email or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? For example, when you put a breakpoint on `if (task.isSuccessful()){` and run the app in a debugger, does it reach that breakpoint? If so, what happens when you step through the code? Which line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: at `if (task.isSuccessful())` always turn false, so it jump to else condition

Comment: In that case, log [`task.getException()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#getException()) to learn the cause of the problem.

Comment: i know my problem typo at `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)` it must 

`auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`

Thank you sir for your help!

Answer (score 0):

i know my problem typo at

`auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)`

it must be

`auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`

Thank you sir for your help!